# Clean edit box text on click

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a form with buttons and edit boxes. I want to clean the edit boxes on mouse click, which event should I use in LRESULT CALLBACK procedure?

```
#define IDC_MAIN_EDIT 102 
HWND hEdit;
```

Comment: What do you mean by clean?

Comment: Just delete all text in edit box. I know how to do this, but I do not know how to make an edit box react on mouse click

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you need to handle the `WM_SETFOCUS` message.  The next thing you need to do, is clear the text as your question states.  In which case you can send `WM_SETTEXT` with a `\0` or a null pointer, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms632644%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)